# LockAcquisitionException and SQLCODE=-911, SQLSTATE=40001, SQLERRMC=68

Tags: java, hibernate, db2, timeout, db2-luw

Hitting this when try to update a row of record from a table.

```
org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1190) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:357) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
```

Here is my java code:

```
@Override
public void updateCurrentStatus(Long paymentHistoryId, String currentStatus) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( );
    sb.append( "update PaymentHistory SET " );
    sb.append( " currentStatus = :currentStatus ," );
    sb.append( " MODIFIEDDATETIME = CURRENT TIMESTAMP " );
    sb.append( "where paymentHistoryId = :paymentHistoryId " );

    final Query updateQuery = getSession( ).createSQLQuery( sb.toString( ) );
    updateQuery.setString( "currentStatus", currentStatus );
    updateQuery.setLong( "paymentHistoryId", paymentHistoryId );
    updateQuery.executeUpdate( );
}
```

PaymentHistory is an entity and paymentHistoryId is the primary key.

Thus, I believe my method will only update just ONE record of PaymentHistory table.

I believe that reason code 68 is not a deadlock, its lock timeout. This will happen if there are more than 1 request to update the same row of record at the same time.

If I can make sure that there is no 2 request to update this record, any other reason to getting this Exception?

My db2 version is DB2/AIX64 10.5.9

Comment: What Db2-version? Which operating-system runs the Db2-server (Z/OS, i-series, Linux/Unix/Windows0 ?

Comment: You get a lock-timeout because at least one connection is waiting too long for a lock. There is no other reason. Consider adjusting (dynamically) the lock timeout inside the app, you can do this at connection level, or with a SET CURRENT LOCK TIMEOUT statement, or with statement-attributes etc.  You can also do it globally at database level. You can also vary the locking behaviour by adjusting the isolation-level of statements or connections, along with varying the CUR_COMMIT database setting.

Comment: DB2/AIX64 10.5.9